# XML only get element if text matches condition

Tags: c#, xml

```
<cataloglist>
  <catalogentry>
    <machinename>PCONE</machinename>
    <rolename>userPC</rolename>
    <rolename>Admin</rolename>
  </catalogentry>
  <catalogentry>
    <machinename>PCTWO</machinename>
    <rolename>userPC</rolename>
    <rolename>Admin</rolename>
    <rolename>Controller</rolename>
  </catalogentry>
</cataloglist>
```

My code below grabs the machine name instantly (as there will only be one), but I could have an undetermined amount of rolenames. I want to scan the rolenames to see if rolename "Admin" exists, for example. Well, the code correctly identifies that "Admin" is a rolename, and enters the if statement, but everything I've tried prints out whitespace. If I remove the conditional the rolenames all output as expected.

```
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(zdPath))
    {
        xmlReader.MoveToContent();
        while(xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if(xmlReader.IsStartElement())
            {
                switch (xmlReader.Name.ToLower())
                {

                    case "machinename":
                        Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.ReadString().Trim());
                        break;
                    case "rolename":
                        if (xmlReader.ReadString() == "Admin")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Value) //Whitespace
                            Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.ReadString());//Whitespace
                        }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My final output ends up looking like this:

```
PCONE
--blank line--
--blank line--
PCTWO
```

Comment: You should use XPath or XSLT for this

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure why this works, but it does. Adding xmlReader.Read() into each case will allow me to know the next elements value. That is what I assume is happening, anyway.

```
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(zdPath))
{
    xmlReader.MoveToContent();
    while(xmlReader.Read())
    {
        if(xmlReader.IsStartElement())
        {
            switch (xmlReader.Name.ToLower())
            {

                case "machinename":
                    xmlReader.Read();
                    string clientName = xmlReader.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Value);
                    break;
                case "rolename":
                    xmlReader.Read();
                    string role = xmlReader.Value;
                    if (role == "Admin")
                    {
                     Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Value);
                    }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```